# Delete entries from ManyToMany table using _raw_delete

Tags: python, django

I have a huge amount of data in my db.
I cannot use .delete() method cause performance of Django ORM is insufficient in my case.
_raw_delete() method suits me cause I can do it python instead using raw SQL.
But I have problem I have no idead how can I delete relation tables using _raw_delete. They need to be deleted before models cause I have restrict in DB. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: For foreign key retaltions, you can make the constraints on delete cascade.

Comment: I forgot to mention. Cascade is not a option here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
You can operate on link model with this:

```
link_model = MyModel._meta.get_field('my_m2m_field').remote_field.through
qs = link_model.objects.filter(mymodel_id__in=mymodel_ids)
qs._raw_delete(qs.db)
```